# Are there any ways to improve this ISR - STM32F401RE?

Tags: stm32, interrupts, stm32f4, remote-control, mbed

I am currently coding a flight controller from scratch and am currently working on the module to decode the incoming PPM signal. Keeping in mind that this is an ISR, I've limited its functionality only to read the channel values from my receiver. It is working totally okay, but I wanted some feedback and improvements on the same (if possible). The ISR is as follows:

```
    void measureChannel(){
   int elapsedTime = t.read_us();
          //if any pulse shorter than 1000us, discard as garbage
   if(elapsedTime < 900){
        t.reset();
        return;
    }

  else{ 
        //if start/stop sequence, then set currentChannel = 1 and begin to read
        if(elapsedTime > 2100) {
                currentChannel = 1;
                t.reset();
                return;
            }
        //read channel value
        else if(elapsedTime >= 1000 && elapsedTime <= 2000){
                if(currentChannel == 1){
                        channelVal[0] = elapsedTime;
                        currentChannel = 2;
                        t.reset();
                        return;
                    }

                else if(currentChannel == 2){
                        channelVal[1] = elapsedTime;
                        currentChannel = 3;
                        t.reset();
                        return;
                    }

                else if(currentChannel == 3){
                        channelVal[2] = elapsedTime;
                        currentChannel = 4;
                        t.reset();
                        return;
                    }

                else if(currentChannel == 4){
                        channelVal[3] = elapsedTime;
                        currentChannel = 5;
                        t.reset();
                        return;
                    }

                else if(currentChannel == 5){
                        channelVal[4] = elapsedTime;
                        currentChannel = 6;
                        t.reset();
                        return;
                    }

                else if(currentChannel == 6){
                        channelVal[5] = elapsedTime;
                        currentChannel = 0;
                        t.reset();
                        return;
                    }
            }
      } 
}
```

The relevant global variables and various instances are initialised as follows:

```
    Timer t;
    InterruptIn ppmPin(PB_5);
    uint16_t channelVal[6];
    uint8_t currentChannel = 1;
```

Comment: Assuming those globals are accessed outside of your ISR they should be declared volatile.

Comment: ... and any of those globals which are *only* accessed inside the ISR, but need to maintain their state between ISR calls I would declare as static *inside* the ISR. That way they're inaccessible from outside the ISR, but do maintain their state between calls.

Comment: `if any pulse shorter than 1000us` not the truth in the real life.

Comment: You should probably be using a timer peripheral for this, rather than software timing, especially given everything else you have to stay on top of.

Comment: Is this the ISR or is it called in the main thread? Noticed theres no clearing of the interrupt. For style, imho ISRs should be kept as short as possible, just clear the interrupt, and ready the system for executing necessary stuff. Not necessary obviously, but  it does help avoid problems when you have lots of interrupts to manage. +1 on using a timer as well

Answer (score 0):

- the return statements are not needed
- for clearity it's better to use some arrays to minimize the code

The read channel value part can be written as:

```
  //read channel value
  else if(elapsedTime >= 1000 && elapsedTime <= 2000)
  {
       if((currentChannel >= 1) && (currentChannel <= 6)) 
       {
             channelVal[currentChannel - 1] = elapsedTime;
             currentChannel = (currentChannel + 1) % 7;
       }
  }
```

Comment: `the return statements are not needed` But it is ok to have one.